# OutOfMemoryError x loadAd(adRequest) x AdActivity

Tags: java, android, mobile

Boa noite.

Alguém conhece a classe `AdActivity`? E alguém sabe se posso usá-la sem problemas com `finish()`?

```
Context acontext = null; 

AdActivity adActivity = (AdActivity) acontext; 

adActivity.finish();
```

Estou com problemas de `OutOfMemoryError` que ocorre quando não chamo o `anuncioView.loadAd(adRequest)` e depois reinicio o app.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Valeu.

Comment: Qual que é o pacote dessa `AdActivity`?

Comment: Não consegui achar a documentação dessa classe `AdActivity`, porém, ela provavelmente estende a classe Activity, então o finish() deve funcionar da mesma forma, para ajudar com o erro, poste o log do crash

Comment: qual e a configuracao do seu AVD? ou vc esta testando em um device ? resondendo o Victor : acho que esse e o pacote com.google.ads.AdActivity